# nothing to commit, working directory clean, however with changes commited

Tags: git, github, branch, commit, git-commit

```
$ git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

This is what I get, when I try to track the changes on README.md file.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I try to track the changes on README.md file"? Has the file definitely changed? Is it definitely not in the .gitignore file?

Comment: Where is file `README.md`? Is it ignored? Is it already tracked and committed?

Comment: @JonSkeet it is not in the .gitignore

Comment: @knittl  no, it is not tracked, or committed before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git log` command instead for tracking changes.
Refer to this for more: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History